# oracle + django + bulk_create + Long text

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using django 1.6.2 + oracle 12 + cx_oracle 5.1.2

here is my model

```
class Value(models.Model):
    text= models.TextField()
```

I have some text and it's  length is 3000 characters in Russian language, when im tring to do that:

```
text = 'some text' #3000 characters

v = Value(text=text)
v.save()
```

it's ok ...

but when i'm doing that:

```
text = 'some text' #3000 characters

v = Value(text=text)
Value.objects.bulk_create([v])
```

I got this exception:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/test/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 3.3.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'haystack',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'modeltranslation',
 'south',
 'core',
 'appl',
 'legacy_data',
 'djcelery')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'tpp.SiteUrlMiddleWare.SiteUrlMiddleWare',
 'tpp.SiteUrlMiddleWare.GlobalRequest')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tpp\tppcenter\views.py" in test
  374.     Value.objects.bulk_create([v])
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in bulk_create
  160.         return self.get_queryset().bulk_create(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in bulk_create
  356.                     self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _batched_insert
  835.                                              using=self.db)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in insert_query
  1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  899.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  535.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py" in execute
  815.             return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /test/
Exception Value: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

But for english characters it's ok...

Answer (score 0):

New ticket has been opened
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22144

Temporary fix:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11580#comment:3